# Can't install msoledbsql - get error saying it needs C++ Redist

Tags: oledb, installshield, sqlncli, sqloledb

I'm trying to make our (Installshield) installers use msoledbsql instead of sqloledb and sqlncli11 and the installer fails when connecting to the database. So I did some research and tried manually installing msoledbsql first (using msoledbsql.msi), but I get the error: The application requires Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2022, version 14.34 at minimum. So I downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.36.32532, but I still get the same message, even after rebooting.

I tried adding both as redistributables (pre-reqs), but I get the same issue.

Anyone come across this and know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found that we needed both the x86 and x64 C++ redistributables as prerequisites. Also the checksum's in the  `.prq` files are wrong, so the xml needed updating with the MD5 hash of the downloaded files:

`certutil -hashfile VC_redist.x86.exe MD5`

`certutil -hashfile VC_redist.x64.exe MD5`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the hint of needing both, the x64 and x86 version of the redistributables. Was pulling my hair out today on this issue because I only had the x64 version installed. On the hindsight, I should have read the docs, where this fact is explicitly mentioned ...